# Installing PostGIS SFCGAL 1.4 extension in the latest official PostGIS docker image (Debian bullseye based)

Tags: postgresql, postgis, docker

I do need to use the [PostGIS SFCGAL extension](https://oslandia.gitlab.io/SFCGAL/) in its latest version (i.e. `1.4.1` at the time of writing).

This extension is based (and needs) the `libsfcgal` system library.

Because the official PostGIS docker image available at https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/ ([`postgis/postgis:15-master`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/layers/postgis/postgis/15-master/images/sha256-d8e9b386e2aa3a575265dda42e412b2a2286b58d551c9b40e619fd62902eb234?context=explore)) is based on Debian 11 (bullseye),
`libsfcgal` version is `1.3.9-2`: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libsfcgal1 and so does the PostGIS extension:

```sql
-- Debian 11 (latest official PG15/PostGIS3.3 docker hub image)
SELECT postgis_full_version();

POSTGIS="3.4.0dev 3.3.0rc2-335-gae95dd219"
  [EXTENSION]
    PGSQL="150"
    GEOS="3.12.0dev-CAPI-1.18.0"
    SFCGAL="1.3.10"
    PROJ="9.2.0"
    LIBXML="2.9.10"
    LIBJSON="0.15"
    LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
    WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
    TOPOLOGY
```

Well, actually `1.3.10`, but the `libsfcgal1` lib is currently not installed in the PostGIS Docker image, don't ask me why, neither where SFCGAL actually comes from... it's like that.

Whereas, e.g on Ubuntu 22.04.1:

```sql
# Ubuntu 22.04
POSTGIS="3.3.2 4975da8"
  [EXTENSION] 
    PGSQL="150"
    GEOS="3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0"
    SFCGAL="SFCGAL 1.4.1, CGAL 5.3.1, BOOST 1.74.0"
    PROJ="8.2.1"
    LIBXML="2.9.13"
    LIBJSON="0.15"
    LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
    WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
    TOPOLOGY
```

(LIBXML is also in an older state in the PostGIS Docker image than on Ubuntu. These two libs are the only one been older in the Docker image; all the other are more recent than on Ubuntu)

On Debian (because PostGIS docker images are based on Debian), the version `1.4.1` is actually available in sid, aka testing: https://packages.debian.org/sid/libsfcgal1

I've tried to installed `libsfcgal1` using the testing apt repository, but then I face some troubles, becase apparently, installing this new `libsfcgal1` version also reset locales to some empty values, therefore, PostgreSQL cannot initialize a new database, neither connect properly to it:

```sh
# psql -U postgres

perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US.utf8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
psql (15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.
```

This is blocking when spinning up a container based on a Dockerfile as, e.g.:

```
FROM postgis/postgis:15-master

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get -y update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install \
  --no-install-recommends libsfcgal1
```

Then when starting a vanilla Compose file based on this Dockerimage:

```sh
$ docker compose up 

[+] Running 3/0
 ⠿ Network project_lan_access  Created                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 ⠿ Volume "project_pgdata"     Created                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 ⠿ Container project-db-1      Created                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
Attaching to project-db-1
project-db-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
project-db-1  | This user must also own the server process.
project-db-1  | 
project-db-1  | initdb: error: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
project-db-1 exited with code 1
project-db-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
project-db-1  | This user must also own the server process.
project-db-1  | 
project-db-1  | initdb: error: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
project-db-1 exited with code 1
project-db-1  | initdb: error: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
project-db-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
project-db-1  | This user must also own the server process.
project-db-1  | 
project-db-1 exited with code 1
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠙ Container project-db-1  Stopping                                                                                                                                                                           0.2s
canceled
```

(which I have to manually stop because it's looping for ever...)

##### EDIT

By trying this Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgis/postgis:15-master

ENV LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 # <-- new line!
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8   # <-- new line!

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian testing main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get -y update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install \
  --no-install-recommends libsfcgal1
```

I have two new warnings (`setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)`) prior to the same error loop than before when spinning up the container:

```sh
$ docker compose up
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Network project_lan_access  Created                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 ⠿ Container project-db-1      Created                                                                                                                                                                        0.1s
Attaching to project-db-1
project-db-1  | bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
project-db-1  | bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
project-db-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
project-db-1  | This user must also own the server process.
project-db-1  | 
project-db-1  | initdb: error: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
project-db-1 exited with code 1
project-db-1  | bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
project-db-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
project-db-1  | This user must also own the server process.
project-db-1  | 
project-db-1  | initdb: error: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
project-db-1 exited with code 1
project-db-1  | initdb: error: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
project-db-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
project-db-1  | This user must also own the server process.
project-db-1  | 
project-db-1 exited with code 1
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container project-db-1  Stopped                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
canceled
```

Therefore, my question is: how to properly install the SFCGAL 1.4.1 extension (as it is available on Ubuntu 22.04 for example) in the latest PostGIS docker image?

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

One cannot simply install `libsfcal1` because the PostGIS Docker image is currently [building SFCGAL from Oslandia](https://github.com/postgis/docker-postgis/blob/4054f0a49d2f5a328feb1e963c609bdf3b40eeb9/15-master/Dockerfile#L69-L81) sources.

### Detailed answer

In order to have PostGIS build with SFCGAL 1.4.1 support, one has to install [`libcgal-dev` 5.5.1](https://packages.debian.org/sid/devel/libcgal-dev) from Debian testing (sid) in its Dockerfile.

Indeed, the `libcgal-dev` version is [`5.2`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/devel/libcgal-dev) on Debian bullseye, and an error is raised when compiling SFCGAL >= 1.4 from sources with this version of `libcgal-dev`:

```sh
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/usr/src/SFCGAL/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:67 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "CGAL" that is compatible
  with requested version "5.3".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/CGAL/CGALConfig.cmake, version: 5.2
```

A quick [workaround](https://github.com/postgis/docker-postgis/pull/336/files) is to fetch `libcgal-dev` 5.5.1 from Debian testing and update the git hash corresponding to the SFCGAL [`1.4.1`](https://gitlab.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/-/tree/v1.4.1) release in the PostGIS Dockerfile.

The PostGIS docker image build should then work, giving you a fully functional PostGIS with SCFGAL 1.4.1 support:

```sql
POSTGIS="3.4.0dev 3.3.0rc2-390-gc2a0b2024"
  [EXTENSION]
    PGSQL="150"
    GEOS="3.12.0dev-CAPI-1.18.0"
    SFCGAL="SFCGAL 1.4.1, CGAL 5.5.1, BOOST 1.74.0"
    PROJ="9.2.0"
    LIBXML="2.9.10"
    LIBJSON="0.15"
    LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
    WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
    TOPOLOGY
```